# Does fork() call compute eventually?

Tags: java, concurrency, fork-join

My understanding is that it creates another thread and runs compute() in another thread.
then join fetches the result once recursively got it.

I would like to know whether `fork()` calls `compute()` or not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the source code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I have checked it and it does not seem so clear to me.

Comment: I can see it's not used on the surface... then how come it does what it does without calling compute?

Comment: by the way source code --> http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror/jsr166y/1.7.0/jsr166y/ForkJoinWorkerThread.java#ForkJoinWorkerThread.pushTask%28jsr166y.ForkJoinTask%29

Comment: Fork() is used to spawn a new process, not a thread. The new process is called 'child process' and the old process is called 'parent process'. The parent process can wait until the child process finishes by calling wait(), not join()

Comment: @DPG It is more common to refer to each 'process' as a task. (ie RecursiveTask and ForkJoinTask).  And you are wrong with respect to the wait and not join.  The RecursiveTask should `fork()` then `compute()` and finally `join()` on the forked task.  NOT `wait()`

Comment: @DPG That's correct for the Unix fork() system call but the question seems to be about the Java API.

Comment: @Rollerball We can say that .fork() call will be executed asynchronously and during this execute() method will be called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fork` method will not call `compute`.  It will push the forked task to a work queue in which the running thread determines if it should eventually call `compute` itself or notify other threads to steal that task and invoke compute.

Comment: And the work queue is shared with the other process right?

Comment: Each thread has their own queue.  But each thread can notify the other threads in the FJ pool to start stealing work from their queue.